# How to get a pointer of list element that stays after sorting in C++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, vector, std

I am holding some 2-D points with x-y coordinates in a list. I have a method which sorts the array according to the distances the points have with the cursor and the method returns the pointer to the point that is closest to the cursor.

However I am using &points.first() and this always points to the first element of the list. However the pointer changes after I resort the list. How do I get a pointer that points to the specific ELEMENT, not the first element of the list.

I've tried:
&points.first()

```
QList<Point2> points;


Point2 *DrawingWidget::closestToCursor(){
    // Current mouse position
    Point2 pos(m_x, m_y);

    // There are no points
    if(points.isEmpty()){
        return NULL;
    }

    // Sorts according to distance to the cursor
    std::sort(std::begin(points), std::end(points), [&pos](Point2 a, Point2 b) {
            return pos.distanceFrom(a) < pos.distanceFrom(b);
    });

    // We dont allow points closer than 50px appart
    if(pos.distanceFrom(points.first()) > 50){
        return NULL;
    }

    // Even after the resort, this always points to the first element of the vector. How do I get this elements pointer instead? 
    // Currently it seems that the pointer is basically LIST+0x0, however if the element shifts to whatever position, how do I still have its pointer?
    return &points.first();
}
```

Each time I call this method near a new point, the pointer just shifts to the first element of the list, which is what it's supposed to DO, I know this. But how do I do it like I need to?

Comment: Don't forget that C++ strongly encourages the use of [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) instead of `NULL`.

Comment: don't use lists if not absolutely necessary. They are, if not evil, then hellish.

Comment: the element in the list is the element. Containers store values not references, hence if you want your objects to have some idendities outside of the list then you could store pointers in the list, but that is often not a good idea, so better use what has been proposed in the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably do linear search to find that element because sorting is more expensive.

Linear search is `O(N)`.

Sorting is `O(N*log2(N))`.

E.g.:

```
auto& found = *std::min_element(std::begin(points), std::end(points),
                                [&pos](Point a, Point b) { return pos.distanceFrom(a) < pos.distanceFrom(b); });
return pos.distanceFrom(found) > 50 ? 0 : &found;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your list ends up sorted, you can find the original first point in `log2(n)` steps using a binary search:

```
#include <algorithm>

Point2 *DrawingWidget::closestToCursor() {
    if (points.isEmpty())
        return NULL;
    Point2 pos(m_x, m_y);
    auto cmpfun = [&pos](Point2 a, Point2 b) {
            return pos.distanceFrom(a) < pos.distanceFrom(b);
    });
    auto firstPoint = points.first();

    std::sort(std::begin(points), std::end(points), cmpfun);
    if (pos.distanceFrom(points.first()) > 50)
        return NULL;

    // return a pointer to the original first point
    return &*std::lower_bound(std::begin(points), std::end(points),
                              firstPoint, cmpfun);
}
```

There are other approaches, such as a [decorate-sort-undecorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to sort the *pointers* and truly retain the original point, but those would likely end up being significantly more expensive to execute.